# Reminder Popup for Past Activities/Tasks doesn't pops for Community User

Tags: community, administration, tasks, task-notifications

Is there any settings to be done for community users to pop up the task list for past/overdue list. For internal users whenever we log in we get a popup for all task/activities which has crossed the dates, But for community users it is not popping up.

Some of my org users are complaining that they are not getting it even once but some are saying it comes only the first time they login in a day.

Is there any kind of setting I need to do to enable it to work just like it does for internal users.

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p300000008XZoAAM

From documentation:-

> Task reminders are now available to partner users in communities. This
>   includes users with a partner portal or Partner Community license.
>
> Partner users in communities can see their reminders by clicking **Your
>   Name** | **My Settings** | **Reminders**